# Slice pattern for list

Tags: python, list, design-patterns, slice

I have a list in which there is an undefined number of elements:

```
l1 = [a, b, c, d ...]
```

I need to create a list such that:

```
l2 = [[a,a],[a,b],[b,b],[b,c],[c,c],[c,d],[d,d],[d,e],...]
```

Now, in order to obtain l2, this is what I did:

```
l1 = sorted(l1*4)[1:-1]
l2 = [l1[x:x+2] for x in xrange(0,len(l1),2)]
```

It works, but I don't like it because in case the number of elements inside l1 is very big then this code will be quite memory (***4**) and time (**sorted**) consuming. Do you have any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it with list comprehensions:

```
In [46]: from itertools import izip, islice

In [47]: l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
In [48]: l2=[x for (a,b) in izip(l1, islice(l1, 1,None)) for x in ([a,a],[a,b])] ; l2 += [[b,b]]

In [49]: l2
Out[49]: 
[['a', 'a'],
 ['a', 'b'],
 ['b', 'b'],
 ['b', 'c'],
 ['c', 'c'],
 ['c', 'd'],
 ['d', 'd'],
 ['d', 'e'],
 ['e', 'e']]
```

Comment: Yes, I prefer a list comprehension! But, before accepting: the list should end with ['e','e']. How do you do that?

Comment: Add `l2 += [[b,b]]` at the end. See my most recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a optimum code in terms of memory use, the best way is using generators, which in this case you can use `itertools` module :

```
>>> def pair_creator(iterator):
...     pairs = chain.from_iterable((repeat(i,2) for i in iterator))
...     forward, pairs = tee(pairs)
...     next(forward)
...     return zip(pairs,forward)
```

All you need here is creating an iterator contains the duplicate pairs of preceding items.

```
new = chain.from_iterable((repeat(i,2) for i in l1))
```

then use `tee` to create 2 independent iterator from current iterator then use use `next` to consume the first item of one of them them use `zip` (`izip` in python 2.X) to get the proper columns.

Demo:

```
>>> l1 = range(10)
>>> pair_creator(l1)
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 4), (4, 5), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 6), (6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 8), (8, 8), (8, 9), (9, 9)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the initial list is in order:

```
l1 = [a, b, c, d ...]
l2 = []
for ii, x in enumerate(l1[:-1]):
    l2.append([x,x])
    l2.append([x,l1[ii+1])
l2.append([l1[-1],l1[-1]) # last element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f         = lambda (x, y): [[x, x], [x, y]]
concat    = lambda xs: sum(xs, [])
concatMap = lambda f, xs: concat(map(f, xs))
```

And here's your function:

```
fn = lambda xs: concatMap(f, zip(xs, xs[1:]))
```